# 'Module build failed: Error' for ng2-slimscroll

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am following below URL to add slim scroll to my application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-slimscroll

Facing below error at compile time:

ERROR in ./~/ng2-slimscroll/index.ts
Module build failed: Error
    at new FatalError (E:\AgreeWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint\lib\error.js:40:23)
    at Function.findConfiguration (E:\AgreeWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint\lib\configurat
ion.js:47:15)
    at resolveOptions (E:\AgreeWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:35:64)
    at Object.module.exports (E:\AgreeWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:124
:17)
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts 24:23-48
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/
app/app.main

Anyone could help me to get out from this.